# Problem with JWT authorization in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, authorization

I'm sending a JWT to my endpoint using the `Authorization` header with the value `Bearer <encoded jwt>`. Here's the payload of the JWT:

```json
{
  "sub": "1",
  "email": "admin@example.com",
  "jti": "4dabc47a-c524-4f23-b271-420235822d3d",
  "role": "admin",
  "exp": 1682255987,
  "iss": "http://localhost:5000",
  "aud": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

However, when I make the request, I receive a `403 Forbidden` response instead of the expected `201 Created`. Here's the code for my endpoint in controller:

```cs
[Authorize("admin")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] ExampleRequest request)
{
    // actual code returning Created()
}
```

authorization config in Program.cs:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("admin", policy =>
        policy.RequireClaim("role", "admin")));
```

I am sure that token hasn't expired. Response headers does't contain anything useful. I have added authorization middleware to app (`app.UseAuthorization();`). Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?

I believe i included all necessary details, but here is [source code](https://github.com/kacperwyczawski/sigma-cars/tree/d8af091f44dcea2172e6e54ddadf56972c2a6dde/Backend/SigmaCars.WebApi) if you want to check it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not what i exactly wanted, but i used [`ClaimTypes.Role`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role?view=net-7.0) instead of `"admin"` for role key, deleted `AddPolicy` in Program.cs, replaced `[Authorize("admin")]` with `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` aaaand  it somehow worked! It it's not answer to question *(because it uses roles instead of policies, as i initialy wanted)* to be honest, but it's an good solution and i'll stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell ASP.NET Core what the name of the role claim is, using something like:

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    ...
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = "role"
    };
    ...
}
```

For more details, you I blogged about these problems here:

- [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)
- [Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, but thanks for your answer

Comment: Remove the AddPolicy and look at what claims that are actually present in the user object. If you get a 403 error, then you have received a valid token, but authorization rejects you. Is the role claim actually in the User object?